# How to write a program that generates 1,000 random die tosses and shows the histogram of the results

Tags: python, python-3.7

I need to write python code that randomizes 1000 numbers of tosses. After, I need to incorporate an histogram using (`*`) asterisk to show the randomization of each number.

I am using Anaconda, Spyder specifically and I've been using what I read in books and what my professor taught us.

```
import random

def dieTosses():
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
count3 = 0
count4 = 0
count5 = 0
count6 = 0
tosses = [random.randint(1, 6) for i in range(0, 1000)]
if tosses == 1:
count1 == count1+ 1
elif tosses == 2:
count2 == count2+ 1
elif tosses == 3:
count3 == count3+ 1
elif tosses == 4:
count4 == count4+ 1
elif tosses == 5:
count5 == count5+ 1
elif tosses == 6:
count6 == count6+ 1
else:
dieTosses()
print('die toss', tosses)
```

It's not randomizing, and for the most part not going anywhere.
Also, I know it's not intended here but it is in spyder.

Comment: couple of things, you need to iterate over the list to actually check the values within it, also I don’t know if you learned about dictionaries in your class but it would make storing and counting your variables easier since you wouldn’t need any if/else statements

Comment: Hiya! Your title should state a question, not an assignment . Also, you need to state your program's output.

Comment: Hint: `if tosses == 1:` will never be true, because tosses is a list, and a list is never equal to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Change that title man, it sounds as if you want us to do your homework.
Remember to indent everything in the function and your if/elif/else statements. You can't call a variable from outside a function. 
1. Indent your code in the proper places
2. Put that Print statement inside the function and maybe change it so it calls count1 through count6 so that it prints those, asking it to print Tosses won't work. Remember to change ints and floats to strs when trying to print them. Hope this helps.